# React Redux -> Why does my reducer behave like that?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I've been working with redux persist and at first I thought it didn't work, after countless of nights spent on debugging the code I installed redux-logger and realized that redux-persist works perfectly as intended but the problem is, rather, within my reducer. The problem is that, actually, the reducer replaces everything that was saved within the store before that and after I call the action add it replaces the saved storage items with the new ones. How can I make it not do that? By the way what I am trying to contain within the store is just a number that I am increasing by pressing a button, the thing is that I want this number to keep increasing even after refresh, not to be replaced by the 0 I've set, but I am lost here.
Here is my reducer's code:

```
import React from 'react'
let counter=0;


const reducer =(state, action)=>
{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'add':
            return{
                ...state, 
                count: counter+=1
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


export default reducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
case 'add':
  const newCount = state.count && state.count !== 0 ? state.count + 1 : count + 1
  return{
    ...state, 
    count: newCount
  }
```

In that way you're checking that the state,count value is valid and is not 0 so you can return that value + 1. If not that means that you have 0 as a value and you should increment that by 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a initialState object that retrieve the count from your local storage. Then in your reducer you can simply return
{...state, count: count+state.count}

Comment: I am not using localStorage, I am using redux persist's storage and it is imported like that `import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'` How can I do that with the redux persist webstorage??

Comment: https://medium.com/@edisondevadoss/how-to-use-redux-persist-in-react-application-35943c1d8292 
if you setup your store correctly, the state.count should be same as the previous session. `return {...state, count: count+state.count}` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your reducer **never looks at the value of the counter that exists in the store**.  It takes the variable `counter` which exists in you file and adds `1` to it.  You want a reducer that adds `1` to the previously stored value.  Local variables in reducer files should be used for declaring initial/default values only.  Your state updates should not depend on them.

For the record, `state` does not have to be an object if all you are storing is a count.  You can have a reducer which just stores a numeric count value.  If you want to add more data, you can use `combineReducers` to handle different properties of your state.

Here's a reducer that handles just a number

```
const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'add':
            return state + 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

If the action is 'add' then we add one to the previous value.  Otherwise we return the value unchanged.  If no value exists, the default argument `state = 0` sets it to `0`.